# Error accessing SASS variables defined in a separate file

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, sass

I'm trying to use Rails 3.2 with Sass. I tried to create a Sass file in my project to define all global variables based on [Railscast #268](http://railscasts.com/episodes/268-sass-basics). But I kept getting Sass::SyntaxError because of undefined variables.

What I have:

application.css.scss

```
/*
*= require_self
*/

@import "variables.css.scss";
@import "layout.css.scss";
```

variables.css.scss

```
$font_size: 14px;
```

layout.css.scss

```
body { 
    font-size: $font_size;
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Any suggestion would be great!

Comment: How does your compiled css file look like? Are all these files in the same folder?

Comment: @markus Yes, they're in the same folder and doesn't throw the syntax error when I access it by http://localhost:3000/assets/application.css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to put the sass files that requieres this variables as partials (for example _layout.css.scss) this will prevent rails to try to compile them individually without their  dependencies.

Comment: Thanks @kumiau! I changed layout.css.scss to _layout.css.scss and it fixed the problem. But strangely, when I changed the _layout.css.scss back to layout.css.scss, It doesn't give me the syntax error anymore.

Comment: Your browser probably had the previous CSS cached